# Faking non-XHR network requests for Cypress

Tags: cypress

I have an AngularJS application and I'm trying to use Cypress to stub some of the network requests that it makes. Currently, my problem is with a request with resource type Img. I know from Cypress documentation that Cypress cannot stub non-XHR resource types/requests, but **I'm looking for a workaround**.

My application requests the image from a backend server, which I want to stub or fake. I prefer not to modify the application code, and would rather create an external workaround.

I've looked into the following and found them not to be useful in this scenario:

- Sinon.js - Similarly can only handle XHR requests.
- nock - Replaces node's `http.request`, but that doesn't seem to work within Cypress. It might work if I added it straight into my application code, which I prefer not to do.

I've also tried the following but was unsuccessful:

- mockserver - Ran the mockserver and added an `expectation`, but none of the requests made to the mockserver seemed to go through.
- Service Worker API - Was unsure about how to `register` my service worker, since it requires a `.js` file as an input. What `.js` file would be served as  input if I'm controlling the service worker via Cypress?
- <s>a mock server using express - The issue is the application is running on `localhost:<some_port>`, while the mock server is running on `localhost:<some_other_port>`. I'm having trouble specifying port numbers when constructing the request through the application. Basically, my application isn't really respecting different port numbers.</s>

---

EDIT:

I've been successful with creating a mock server using express. According to Cypress documentation, servers shouldn't be started and stopped within `before()` and `after()`'s. Instead, they should be started prior to Cypress being started, and stopped after Cypress is stopped.